deploy a powershell script to 50 devices using Intune
I wrote a powershell script that I'm going to deploy to 50 devices using Intune. The script deletes the browser cache data in Chrome. I have not deployed through Intune yet. On a test machine, I placed the script in a directory and executed it. I got the following error:
File C:\scripts\deleteGoogleCache.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is 
disabled on this system. For more
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
LinkID=135170.
+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

So, I search for a solution. I'm supposed to run PowerShell as an administrator. Obviously, I'm not going to each device and run powershell as an administrator. So, I found another tip by issuing this command:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

and I got the following response.
Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the 
execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution 
policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"):

Obviously, I'm not physically going to every device and press [A] for Yes to all.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, I'm new to Powershell.

Have you tried running powershell in bypass mode?  Use intune to copy the file to the system then execute it with:
powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File MyScript.ps1
